# check for Continuity $x \rightarrow 2x^4-2$

Tags: calculus, functions, limits, continuity, problem-solving

Given the function: $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R},\quad x \rightarrow 2x^4-2$

i am asked to check for Continuity for all values of $x$. i am now overasked how to do this since $\Bbb{R}$ is not a small range of numbers.

Definition: the Continuity of a function means that a function isnot to have any holes o jumps in its graph.

how do i check this for all domain values of $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know about the $\epsilon - \delta$ criteria ?

Comment: Okay the problem is, that the real definition about continuity is not "does not have any jumps or holes", but rather that if you take two values on the x-axis that are arbitary close to each other, then the function values on the y-axis also become arbitary close.

Comment: If you've learned the limit laws, you can compute $$f\left( \lim_{x \to a} x \right)$$ and $$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) $$ to see if they're equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your definition for continuity? Well I suggest looking the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E4-2) of $f$
and see if there are any "holes" or "jumps".

Let's do this in a rigorous manner:

The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition:
Let $a\in X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. Then we say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if \begin{equation}\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0:\ \left|x-a\right|<\delta\implies \left|f(x)-f(a)\right|<\epsilon\end{equation}
If $f$ is continuous at every point of $A\subseteq X$ then $f$ is said to be (pointwise) continuous on $A$.

It is usually hard to prove continuity using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. When one has studied limits of sequence this becomes much simpler using the following equivalent definition due to Heine :

Let $a\in X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff for every sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $X$, $x_n\to a\implies f(x_n)\to f(a)$

Using this we have to prove that if $x_n\to a$ for arbitrary $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(x_n)\to f(a)$ or equivalently $2x_n^4-2\to 2a-2$. I will let you prove that.

Sidenote:

Even as is, your non rigorous definition is wrong because it allows essential discontinuities to be continuities. Look at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csin%201/x) of $f(x)=\sin (1/x)$ $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Is $f$ continuous?

EDIT: We need to prove that 
$$x_n\to a\implies f(x_n)\to f(a)$$
 **not** for a particular $x_n,a$ but **for all** sequences $x_n$ and points $a$.

Now let $x_n$ be a sequence and $a\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $x_n\to a$. Then $f(x_n)=2x_n^4-2$ while $f(a)=2a^4-2$. We need to prove that
$$f(x_n)\to f(a)\iff 2x_n^4-2\to 2a^4-2\iff x_n^4\to a^4$$
(the equivalencies are due to the limit laws). So the problem moves to proving that $x_n^4\to a^4$. But this also follows from the limit laws as $x_n\to a\implies x_n\cdot x_n\to a\cdot a\implies...\implies x_n^4\to a^4$

Comment: Okay, thank you, i will try to prove then

Comment: @doniyor No! You mustn't show that $x_n\to a$. You must **prove** that $f(x_n)\to f(a)$ **assuming** $x_n\to a$

Comment: Nameless, i got it finally. i took $x_{n}:=\frac{2n+1}{1+n}$ and $x_{n} \rightarrow 2$ so now i have to show.  $2(\frac{2n+1}{1+n})^4-2 \rightarrow 2(2)^4-2$, right?

Comment: @doniyor That is just *one* special sequence $x_n$ that convergese to just *one* special real number $2$. You have to show the same statement for *all* sequences converging to *any* real number.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks, but how do i show it? thru induction?

Comment: @doniyor I don't see much applicability of induction here. Anyway, I think you shold first contemplate what is *really* the definition of continuity you are supposed to use. "no holes or jumps" or $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion or sequence continuity or ...